# How to calculate the correct index for array

Tags: arrays, swift, math

I have implemented a tableView which works similar to below example. I want to calculate the correct index for array so it is not out of range. I'm trying to achieve cell 1 To be space 2nd to be cell with data and it repeats

```
 let array = ["0","1","2"] // this is the data with comes for the server so if the count is 3 the cell with data will be 3 and 3 will be just empty cell

 let totalCount = array.count*2

 for i in 0...totalCount {
     if i % 2 == 1{
         //Cell with data is shown here 
         print("Index: \(i-1)") // i'm doing somthing wrong here i need the i to be Index to be "0,1,2"
         print(array[i-1]) // how do i print the data from array at Index 0,1,2
     }else {
         //Space Cell
     }

 }
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying the size of the array by 2?

Comment: @FelixSFD so i can display space Cell for eg. 1st cell is Space than 2nd one is the cell with data then again space

Comment: looks like you might want to use a two dimensional array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, there will always be a point, where `i-1` will be lager than `array.count`. I guess you want to achieve this:

```
Cell: 0; empty cell
Cell: 0; Index 0
Value: 0
Cell: 2; empty cell
Cell: 2; Index 1
Value: 1
Cell: 4; empty cell
Cell: 4; Index 2
Value: 2
Cell: 6; empty cell
```

This can be achieved like this:

```
let array = ["0","1","2"]

let totalCount = array.count*2

for i in 0...totalCount {
    if i % 2 == 1{
        //Cell is shown here
        print("Cell: \(i-1); Index \(i/2)")
        print("Value: \(array[i/2])")
    }else {
        //Space Cell
        print("Cell: \(i); empty cell")
    }

}
```

`i-1` should be the index of the cell, not of the data in your array. The index of the data displayed in the cell should be `i/2` instead, to ensure, this value will never be larger than `array.count`.

Comment: The iteration, where `i` is 6, is an empty cell, because `6 % 2 = 0`

Comment: @O-mkar where is your index 3? Your array doesn't have that index

Comment: `array.count` should be the length of `array`. Never use an other value than that

Comment: @O-mkar The output is `0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 `, because you've set these values in your array